# Why are my constructors recognized as methods?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I am working on a program to hold bank accounts as objects. The accounts have an interest rate, balance, ID, and date created data  to go along. In what I have made, the default balance, id, and interest is 0 from what I understand. The interest rate is undefined by default. The book I am learning form shows that a no-arg constructor is done with "Circle() { }".I used "account() { }" in the account class. When I run the program in jGRASP, I get error "invalid method declaration; return type required" for both of my constructors. It is recognizing what I intend to be constructors as methods. What do I need to understand so I can make my constructors not be recognized as methods?

When running the first constructor, I understand we create an Account object called account with the default values. When we run the second constructor, we are changing the values of the account object to something with specified

```
public class Bank{

public static void main(String[] args){

Account account = new Account(1122, 20000);

account.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);

account.withdraw(2500);

account.deposit(3000);


   System.out.println("Balance is " + account.getBalance());

   System.out.println("Monthly interest is " + account.getMonthlyInterest());

   System.out.println("This account was created at " + account.getDateCreated());

                                     }

                             }


  class Account {

             private int id = 0;

             private double balance = 0;

             private double annualInterestRate = 0;

             private String dateCreated;



              account(){

              }

             account(int newID, double newBalance){

             id = newID;

             balance = newBalance;

             }

        //accessor for ID
        public int getID(){
        return id;
        }
        //acessor for balance
        public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
        }
        //accessor for interest rate
        public double getAnnualInterest(){
        return annualInterestRate;
        }
        //mutator for ID
        public void setID(int IDset){
        id = IDset;
        }
        //mutator for balance
        public void setBalance(int BalanceSet){
        balance = BalanceSet;
        }
        //mutator for annual interest
        public void setAnnualInterestRate(double InterestSet){
        annualInterestRate = InterestSet;
          }
        //accessor for date created
        public String getDateCreated(){
        return dateCreated;
        }
        //method that converts annual interest into monthly interest and returns the value
        public double getMonthlyInterest(){
        double x =  annualInterestRate / 12;
        return x;
          }
       //method that witdraws from account
       public double withdraw(double w){
       balance -= w;
       return balance;
       }
       //method that deposits into account
       public double deposite(double d){
       balance += d;
       return balance;
       }




  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constructor names must match the class names in a *case sensitive* way.  In the `Account` class, change

```
account(){
```

to

```
Account(){
```

and likewise for your other constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You need to capitalize your a in both constructors. Java is case sensitive.

```
          Account(){

          }

         Account(int newID, double newBalance){

             id = newID;

             balance = newBalance;

         }
```

Otherwise, Java sees this as a method with no return type. Remember, a constructor does not have or needs a return type.

Comment: Edit: constructors CANNOT have return types

Answer (score 0):

Constructors should be camelized(as a convention, same with the class name) and it return only the type of itself 
see my example :)

```
Account() {
 return;
}
```